# Polynomial question: find $a$ such that all roots are real.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, parametric

Original question: let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},f(x)=\frac {x^2+ax+5}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}.$ Find $a$ such that f has 3 distinct local extreme points.

So I differentiated the function and got:$$f'(x)=\frac {x^3-3x+a}{(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

So then question is reduced to: find $a$ such that $x^3-3x+a=0$ has all $3$ roots real and distinct.

Comment: There are three distinct roots iff there are two distinct stationary points of the cubic at which the function takes different signs. The stationary points of this one are at $\pm\sqrt{1}$ (different, checked). Now enforce that evaluating them on the polynomial gives different signs.

Comment: @totoro what do you mean by "stationary points"?

Comment: Oh, was referring to zeros of the derivative of $x^3-3x+a$. You know, for three different roots, the cubic should have two humps and they should happen at different sides of the $X$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the proper range for $a$, you may look at it as follows:

- $h(x) = x^3-3x+a = x(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{3}) + a$
- So, how far can you shift the graph of $c(x) = x(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{3})$ upwards and downwards,resp., without the local extrema of $c(x)+a$ reaching the $x$-axis
- local extrema of $c(x)$ are at $x_M = -1$ and $x_m = 1$
- $c(x_M) = 2$ and $c(x_m) = -2 \Rightarrow -2 < a < 2$

Comment: hmm, I understanded it better like this, also, can you be more explicit with the "how for can you shift the graph of $c(x)$ upwards and downwards such that local extrema of $c(x) + a$ reaching the $x$-axis?

Comment: The graph of $c(x)$ intersects the $x$-axis at three points. When adding $a$, we just shift the graph of $c(x)$ upwards or downwards depending on the sign of $a$. (It might be worth doing this with GeoGebra or Desmos or another graphing tool.). As long as $|a| < \min{(|c(x_M)|,|c(x_m)|)}$ the local maximum point stays above the $x$-axis and the local minimum point stays below the $x$-axis. So, there are still three distinct roots to $c(x) + a$.

Comment: yeah, i did it with desmos but I requested additional explanation because I don't think I'll be able to do it without desmos or some graphing tool again. so you're telling me $c(x) + a$ should intersect $x$-axis in 3 points and only in 3 points by the question restrictions so I should find a maxima and minima for $c(x)$ for $a$ to be between them?

Comment: So if I have a problem with $f(x) = m$ and I have to find for which I have to find for what values of $m$ $f(x)$ has *a number of roots*, I have to find the some locally minima and maxima of f(x) such that there can be *"the number of roots"* intersected by the $y = m$ equation? and then $m$ should be between the maxima and minima? And $m$  will always be with the open interval and closed interval?

Comment: Fact is, that the number of solutions of $f(x) = m$ is equal to the number of intersection points of the graph of $f(x)$ and the line $y = m$. So, of course, the position of local extrema of $f$ influences the number of roots of $f(x) = m$. In your case we deal with a cubic function with three distinct zeros and two local extrema in between. This makes it specifically easy to spot the range of $a$. For other functions this might be not so easy.

Comment: I see, so the "casual" approach for a problem like this would just be: *find all the local minima and maxima* and then adapt it for the problem's restriction... right?

Comment: Right. As long as the function is "nice" enough, it works quite well. It might get a bit cumbersome if the function has plenty of local extrema.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^3-3x+a$ is a cubic polynomial, all you need is for its local extrema to have opposite signs. The extrema occur at the zeros of the derivative, $3x^2-3$, i.e., at $x=\pm1$, with the local maximum at $x=-1$ and the local minimum at $x=1$.  So we need

$$(-1)^3-3(-1)+a\gt0\gt1^3-3\cdot1+a$$

or $2+a\gt0\gt-2+a$, which can be rewritten as

$$2\gt a\gt-2$$